# How to detect when UIviewcontroller becomes active again after pushing a child view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How to detect when UIviewcontroller becomes active again after pushing a child view?  Ie when using Uinavigatipncontroller

Ie which callback method in the parent uiviewcontroleer to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for an iPhone app, then `viewDidAppear:` or possibly `viewWillAppear:` will get called when the child view goes away.

Comment: Any advise re telling which child controller you are returning from?

Comment: @Greg. Use a delegate. Each child should take a delegate that is a different protocol. The parent should implement all the protocols in question and the children should tell their delegate when they are done. Then the parent dismisses the child and knows which child is getting dismissed.

Comment: on the iPad, viewWillAppear will not be called when the app is reopen again from the background.